# Lubuntuでchromeを既定のブラウザにしたい

Tags: linux, google-chrome, ubuntu, firefox

LubuntuにChromeとFirefoxがインストールしてあります。
既定のブラウザをFirefoxからChromeに変更するにはどうしたらよいでしょうか？
Thunderbird（メーラー）でメールに記述されているURLをクリックしたら、Chromeが起動するようにしたいです。

以下は、思い当たるところを調査した内容です。

### # ブラウザの設定内容

Firefoxの設定を見ると、Firefoxが既定のブラウザになっています。
Chromeの設定を見ると、既定ブラウザの欄に「Google Chrome では既定のブラウザを判断または設定できません。」と表示され、既定のブラウザに変更するボタンは見当たりませんでした。

### # LXSession configration の設定内容

メニュー>設定>LXSessionのデフォルトアプリケーション
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
WebbrowserにはChromeが設定されています。

### # update-alternatives --config x-www-browser

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser
alternative x-www-browser (/usr/bin/x-www-browser を提供) には 2 個の選択肢があります。

  選択肢    パス                         優先度  状態
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable   200       自動モード
  1            /usr/bin/firefox                40        手動モード
  2            /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable   200       手動モード

現在の選択 [*] を保持するには Enter、さもなければ選択肢の番号のキーを押してください: 0
```

### # Lubuntu バージョン

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid
```

Comment: 既定ブラウザの設定がプログラミングの質問なのかと問われると、ちょっと違うかと思いますが、Lubuntu上でのウェブプログラミング開発環境構築の一環として質問させていただきました。

Comment: 当初は既定ブラウザがThunderbirdから起動されるブラウザであると勘違いしていた為、Thunderbirdを絡めて質問させていただきました。しかし、Thunderbirdが起動するブラウザはThunderbird固有の設定でした。結果的にThunderbirdに関する質問の様になってしまいましたが、私の様に勘違いされている方もいるかもしれないので、当質問を削除せずに残させていただきます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lubuntuのデスクトップ環境であるLXDEでデフォルトアプリケーションを設定するのはLXSession configrationで行います。

メニュー>設定>LXSessionのデフォルトアプリケーション

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

また、xdg-mimeコマンドを使ってデフォルトアプリケーションの設定や、設定内容の確認も可能です。

デフォルトブラウザの設定

```
xdg-mime default google-chrome.desktop x-scheme-handler/http
xdg-mime default google-chrome.desktop x-scheme-handler/https
xdg-mime default google-chrome.desktop text/html
```

デフォルトブラウザの確認

```
xdg-mime query default text/html
xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/http
xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/https
```

ただ、Thunderbird（メーラー）でメールに記述されているURLをクリックした時に起動されるブラウザの設定はLXDEとは別で、Thuderbird固有の環境設定になります。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

参考サイト
http://rest.seesaa.net/article/195829185.html
http://www.nishishi.com/blog/2014/06/thunderbird_bro.html
※参考サイトの画像はWindowsの物になりますが、Linuxでもほぼ同様です。

Answer (score 3):

現在ですと https://archlinuxjp.kusakata.com/wiki/Xdg-open あたりを参考に、

```
xdg-mime default google-chrome.desktop x-scheme-handler/http
xdg-mime default google-chrome.desktop x-scheme-handler/https
xdg-mime default google-chrome.desktop text/html
```

を実行して環境変数 `BROWSER` も設定しておけば、たいていの環境でうまくいくと思われます。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。xdg-mimeで確認してみたところ、google-chrome.desktopが設定されていました。どうやら、Thunderbirdでurlをクリックした時に起動されるブラウザの設定はThunderbird固有の設定のようです。